# Плюсы и минусы подключения сторонних JS библиотек из сторонних ресурсов, просто ссылаясь на ресурс

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Например, вот так

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну например в китае может не подтянуться jquery =) там гугл заблокирован =)

Answer (score 0):

-если удалённый ресурс не доступен или доступ к нему затруднён, то у вас так же будут проблемы.

+меньше файлов.

+как правило такие популярные библиотеки кэшируются браузером => загрузка идёт быстрее.